# How to add quotation makes on either side of an variable with ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying an angularjs variable with `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div style="font-style:italic;font-size:18px">
    "<span ng-bind-html="quote.body"></span>"
</div>
```

which is parsed with the quotation marks outside the `span` like this:

```
<div style="font-style:italic;font-size:18px">
"
<span ng-bind-html="quote.body" class="ng-binding">The level of scientific illiteracy in America provides fertile soil for <strong>political appeals based on ignorance</strong>.
```

"

How can I get the quotation marks inside of the span like this:

```
<div style="font-style:italic;font-size:18px">
    <span class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="quote.body">"Testing."</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is the html you are trying to output?

Comment: Sorry, I had generized it for the example, I put an actual quote back in with bold text, e.g. `<span ng-bind-html="quote.body" class="ng-binding">The level of scientific illiteracy in America provides fertile soil for <strong>political appeals based on ignorance</strong>.
</span>`.

Comment: So what actually happens when you try to output that? Are you trying to output html that has ng-bind in it?

Comment: The problem is not the parsing of the HTML tags, but that I want to get the quotation marks inside the span element, but can't do it if I am using ng-bind-html. If I was just outputting plain text, I would use this approach: `<div style="font-style:italic;font-size:18px;margin: 0 0 10px 0">"{{quote.body}}"</div>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several alternatives. One is to add the quotation marks right to the expression:

```
<span ng-bind-html="'&quot;' + quote.body + '&quot;'"></span>
```

The more preferable one is to use css. It separates the styling from the actual content, is maintainable (changes in one place only) and gives you more freedom with regard to styling:

```
.quote:before, .quote:after {
  content: '"';
}

<span class="quote" ng-bind-html="quote.body"></span>
```

The last alternative that comes to my mind is to write your own directive. It could be as simple as using one of the above solutions and has the advantage that it separates the solution from the usage. That means you can change the solution without touching the HTML:

```
app.directive('quote', function() {
   return {
    scope: {
      quote: '='
    },
    template: '<span ng-bind-html="\'&quot;\' + quote.body + \'&quot;\'"></span>'
  };
});

<span quote="quote"></span>
```

I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0lWYdoh9PeWCtCe4wPWf?p=preview) that shows all three solutions.